# Working with jquery id selectors

Tags: jquery

I am working on a jquery function to convert all the ag-grid table data (header and rows) into HTML plain data.

```
This is my copy function:
  scope.copyRows = [];
    scope.copyTable = function(tableId) {
     console.log($("#" + tableId ).children());
     scope.copyRows = [];

     var i = -1;
     $("#" + tableId).find(".ag-row").each(function(){
     console.log(tableId);
     console.log($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-container"));
     i++;
     var rowNum = i;
     scope.copyRows[rowNum] = [];
     $(this).children(".ag-cell").each(function(){
     scope.copyRows[rowNum].push({"text"  : $(this).text(), "style" :   $(this).attr("style"),"class" : $(this).attr("class").replace("ag-cell", "").replace("ag-cell-no-focus","")});
   });
  });
 }
```

Above is my function, it works fine and prints all the rows of a table. I am not very sure and confused how to also make this function print the headers of the ag-grid table. I am looking for .ag-header-container in the div and trying to call that like this:

```
$("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-container").children(".ag-row").each(function(){
    console.log(tableId);
    console.log($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-group").children());
    i++;
    var rowNum = i;
    scope.copyRows[rowNum] = [];
    $(this).children(".ag-cell").each(function(){
        scope.copyRows[rowNum].push({"text"  : $(this).text(), "style" :   $(this).attr("style"),"class" : $(this).attr("class").replace("ag-cell", "").replace("ag-cell-no-focus","")});
    });
});
```

This does not return any data. I am not sure why is this failing? May be because the page has many tables it does not know which .ag-header-container I am referring to. But why would it not recognize the container as I am using an #id to distinguish between separate tables. Any help would be greatly appreciable.

```
This function worked after some hours of trial and error:

 $("#" + tableId).find(".ag-row, .ag-header-container").each(function(){
 // console.log(tableId);
// console.log($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-body-container").children(".ag-  row"));

   i++;
   var rowNum = i;
   // alert($(this).children(".ag-cell").length);
   scope.copyRows[rowNum] = [];
   $(this).find(".ag-cell, .ag-header-cell").each(function(){
   scope.copyRows[rowNum].push({"text"  : $(this).text(), "style" : $(this).attr("style"),"class" : $(this).attr("class").replace("ag-cell",  "").replace("ag-header-cell", "").replace("ag-header-group-cell", "").replace("ag-cell-no-focus","")});
  });
 });
}
```

How can implement styling to this function. I want to add some customized cell styling for this HTML data. How do I execute that in this code?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a space in `.children(".ag- row")` selector

Comment: Thanks Diego, it still doesn't work fixing that. I don't have that space in my code though!

Comment: Add the following alerts before the `each` sentence: `alert($("#" + tableId).length);` `alert($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-container").length);` `alert($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-container").children(".ag- row").length);`

Comment: I added the above alerts and it gives as length=1. Since I have a "convert to HTML" button next to each table. While, clicking the button, the alert windows above open consequently showing the length as "1".

Comment: If the three alerts show `1`, then the `each` must be executed. You can try `alert($(this).children(".ag-cell").length);` before the inner `each`

Comment: It doesn't execute the inner each line I guess the alert window does not pop out.

Comment: Do the `console.log` lines execute? What happens if you add an alert before `scope.copyRows[rowNum] = [];`?

Comment: It doesn't recognize the last alert even placing it there. The console.log for  console.log($("#" + tableId).find(".ag-header-container").children(".ag-row")); does not execute.

Comment: If the execution stops between the both `console.log`, there must be some error (shown in the console after the `tableId` log).

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback and guidance it finally worked !